# How to create a 1-hour timer with an ATtiny13A microcontroller?

Tags: arduino-ide, time, attiny13

I want to control an AC load such that it powers on for 1 minute, then turns off for 1 hour, then on again for 1 min, and so on, in a loop.

I just modified the blink sketch to do:

1. Turn `A1` on
2. Then delay for 60,000 ms
3. Then turn `A1` off
4. Then delay for 3,600,000 ms (3,600 sec, or 1 hour)

...but it doesn't seem to work.

It looks like the LED connected to `A0` turns on but instead of turning off after 1 min, it turns off after 8 min 30 s.

Any suggestions?

---

I rectified the sketch. Now it takes 1 sec as actual 1 sec. I chose 1 MHz clock in IDE.

```cpp
int ledPin =  A3; // the number of the LED pin
int ledState = HIGH; // ledState used to set the LED
unsigned long previousMillis = 0; // will store last time LED was updated
unsigned long OnTime = 60000; // milliseconds of on-time
unsigned long OffTime = 10000; // milliseconds of off-time

void setup()
{
  // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  // check to see if it's time to change the state of the LED
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if((ledState == HIGH) && (currentMillis - previousMillis >= OnTime))
  {
    ledState = LOW;  // Turn it off
    previousMillis = currentMillis; // Remember the time
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState); // Update the actual LED
  }
  else if ((ledState == LOW) && (currentMillis - previousMillis >= OffTime))
  {
    ledState = HIGH;  // turn it on
    previousMillis = currentMillis; // Remember the time
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState); // Update the actual LED
  }
}
```

Then it turns on for 1 sec and then turns off for 1 sec, then randomly turns on at 30 sec or 1 min 30 sec. I want to turn it on for 1 min every hour.

**I tried the Blink sketch modified as follows:**

```cpp
void setup() {
  pinMode(A3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(A3, HIGH);
  delay(60000);
  digitalWrite(A3, LOW);
  delay(900000);
}
```

But it still turns on for 1 min and turns off for 1 min.

I also tried this:

```cpp
void setup() {
  pinMode(A3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(A3, HIGH);
  delay(60000);
  digitalWrite(A3, LOW);
  delay(3.6e+6);
}
```

No matter what I do on time and off time, it always remains the same.

I wanted to know one thing: can I set a 1-hour off and 1-min on timer using ATtiny13A or not?

I tried 1.2 MHz, 1 MHz, all clocks in the IDE, nothing seems to work.

Comment: What are you running this on?

Comment: Are you sure, that the Attiny is running at the frequency, that you think it runs? I once had my Attiny85 configured for 1MHz instead of the 8MHz, that I was expecting, so I wondered why my code was running 8 times slower.

Comment: How fast does the LED blink when you run the original and unchanged blink sketch?

Comment: Its about 8.4 seconds

Comment: Sounds like ChrisL nailed it. Your attiny13a is running at 1 MHz instead of 8.

Comment: How are you programming the ATtiny? Which programmer and board manager do you use?

Comment: I use arduino mega as isp attiny on breadboard

Comment: Please post your *exact* code. What are your variable types? `int`, for example, can only hold up to `32767` ms, NOT `3600000` ms! It is [2 bytes on AVR microcontrollers](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/int/). That means `unsigned int` only holds up to `65535` ms.

Comment: Please move all your answers that are additions to your question to your question, then delete all your answers that aren't answers. It's okay to write an answer to your own question, but if you're just trying to improve your question, edit your question and add directly to your question instead.

Answer (score 2):

As the unchanged blink sketch blinks with 8.4 seconds, I think my assumption is right. The clock of the Attiny is running 8 times slower, than the code thinks.

When you have installed the Attiny core, there should be a menu entry for the clock frequency. Most likely the standard is 8MHz. But having 8MHz set does not mean, that the Attiny is using 8MHz. To choose between different clock sources and frequencies, you must change the fuses of the microcontroller (which are just some bits of special non-volatile memory in the chip, that set special hardware configuration; more information in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/what-are-atmel-fuses)). This is done, when you burn the bootloader to the chip. That's the easy version. Alternatively you can use the `avrdude` command directly to set the fuses. That's the advanced way.

Currently the fuses of your Attiny seem to be set to the 1MHz internal clock. But the compiler uses the frequency, that you have chosen in the menu, hence 8MHz internal clock. So the compiler thinks, that the chip runs at 8MHz and thus generates the timing code for this execution speed. But your chip is currently 8 times slower, than the compiler thinks.

**TL;DR:** Burn the bootloader onto the chip to let the Arduino IDE set the right fuses for your clock frequency.

Comment: I doubt an ATtiny13a is large enough for a bootloader, having only 1K of Flash / program memory. My experience with ATtinyCore (which does not support the tiny13 AFAIK) is that it correctly sets the fuses when choosing the "burn bootloader" option even when, in the board settings, the "ATTiny XX (No Bootloader)" option is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote should work as expected. If it doesn't, I suspect
there is something broken in the Arduino core you are using. However,
such a trivial task can very easily be programmed in plain C, at the
avr-libc level:

```cpp
#define F_CPU 1000000  // 1 MHz
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
    DDRB |= _BV(PB3);  // PB3 as output
    for (;;) {
        PORTB |= _BV(PB3);   // PB3 high
        _delay_ms(60e3);     // 1 min
        PORTB &= ~_BV(PB3);  // PB3 low
        _delay_ms(3.6e6);    // 1 h
    }
}
```

I would compile it with:

```
avr-gcc -mmcu=attiny13a -Os -Wall -Wextra 1h-timer.c -o 1h-timer.elf
```

See the [Port Registers](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation) Arduino tutorial for the meaning of the
macros used here. You can tweak `F_CPU` to fine-tune the delays, in case
your ATtiny clock is not quite 1 MHz.

Answer (score 0):

Attiny13 has very as in very small memory. So if you want it to crunch stuff which seems to be easy for other mcu, it might not have enough memory for it. It cannot for example consistently carry out millis() like in:

long timeStart = millis();
.
.
.
if (timeIsUp=0 && millis()-timeStart=>60000)
.
.
.

The most that that code will loop is less than 50 seconds in my experience.

As a workaround I was able to make attiny13 keep track of time for more than 10 minutes by using only integers and using count. The count being incremented after 10seconds. So example:

for (int i=0; i>10; i++){
delay(10000);
count++;

Then you can use count to keep track of time that has elapsed.

Using millis() is very heavy for attiny13.